# RDLC Math error handing

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

I the expression below is not working giving #error result if  txtTotalFixedAsset3 has 0

```
=IIf(ReportItems!txtTotalFixedAsset3.Value<> 0 ,(ReportItems!txtTotalFixedAsset.Value  /ReportItems!txtTotalFixedAsset3.Value)*100 , 0)
```

what am i going wrong?

```
=IIf(ReportItems!txtTotalFixedAsset3.Value<> cDec(0) ,(ReportItems!txtTotalFixedAsset.Value  /ReportItems!txtTotalFixedAsset3.Value)*100 ,cDec(0))
```

I also tried this. but no success. txtTotalFixedAsset3 value is of type decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be trying to evaluate the arguments in the `Iif` regardless of whether the condition is true or not.  Try:

```
=ReportItems!txtTotalFixedAsset.Value /
     IIf(ReportItems!txtTotalFixedAsset3.Value = 0
        , 1
        , ReportItems!txtTotalFixedAsset3.Value)
     *100
```

Of course this assumes that if `txtTotalFixedAsset3` is 0 then `txtTotalFixedAsset` is 0 as well.  If not then it truly is a divide by 0 error.